# Couldn't get ros package for lunar Release

Tags: 23.04, ros

I am trying to build ROS Noetic on Ubuntu 23.04 and python 3.11.4 from source. [Referring to the offical ROS documentation](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Source).

Step 1: Installing bootstrap dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-rosdep python3-rosinstall-generator python3-vcstools python3-vcstool build-essential
```

Gives the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python3-rosdep
E: Unable to locate package python3-vcstool
```

Step 2: For this, the documentation asks to add the packages.ros.org debian repository to apt source lists: [click here](https://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list):

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

I tried the above step and it was executed without producing any error.

But, I am still getting the same error when I tried Step 1 after Step 2 again.

Also, after step 2 when I run:

```
sudo apt update
```

It says:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease               
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease            
Ign:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lunar InRelease                       
Hit:6 https://mirror.mwt.me/shiftkey-desktop/deb any InRelease
Err:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lunar Release                      
404  Not Found [IP: 2605:bc80:3010::134 80] 
Get:8 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/npreining:/debian-ubuntu-
onedrive/xUbuntu_22.04./InRelease [1,604 B]
Reading package lists... Done        
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

When I visited to [ROS packages repository](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/), I couldn't see the the folder for Ubuntu 23.04 (lunar), does it mean that there is no package available yet for Ubuntu 23.04?

I haven't installed ROS from source before, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Apt sources are simply URLs. You can open them in a web browser. Did you try http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/ to confirm that Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) is listed there?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) is not there.

Comment: That's your answer. That's why you are having problems building ROS for 23.04. It's not there.